# How to print diamon in sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, replicate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDoLL.png)

I wanted to draw a dimaond like this in Sql. Can you help me please

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 2):

**I have find this code in [queryexamples.com](https://www.queryexamples.com/sql/general/print-pattern-examples-using-sql/) there are to many examples like this**

```
Declare @i int = 0,@max int = 11,@c int = 1
While (@i<@max)
Begin
    Print space(abs((@max-@c)/2))+ Replicate('X',@c)    
    Set @i = @i + 1
    if(@i>(@max/2))
        Set @c -= 2
    else
        Set @c += 2
End
```